# Are low carb protein shakes ok if youre not exercising?

Tags: protein-shakes

[image]

Hi! My name is Shawna. Currebtly, im 270lbs and 5’4. I started low carb about a month ago and have been feeling great except I feel like crap after my breakfast - normally eggs and some kind of protein, so i thought maybe i could just have a low carb protein shake in the morning as a meal replacement. I dont know anything about protein shakes or bcaas. Obviously, im trying to lose weight and i dont wwnt wnything to impede my efforts. Im not currently working out st the moment as i wanted to get my diet under control then i planned on lifting only. Possibly walking a few miles on my treadmill. Will using this protein shake help me get close to my goals or no? My stomach just feels so quesy in the mornings and it sucks. I feel like a shake would coat my stomach and really help. Opinion? Thoughts? [image][image]

Comment: You should just skip breakfast altogether. Contrary to popular belief, it is NOT an important meal, and most people are better off skipping it completely. Your body gets a natural increase in blood sugar when you wake up, and adding breakfast on top of that only spikes it further. A low-carb breakfast is recommended if you really feel the need for breakfast, but I strongly advise you to figure out if you really do need it.

Comment: As for the protein shake, no. Drop that. Food supplements are meant to *supplement* a regular diet. Not replace it. Also, if you're getting a lot of protein, without stimulating muscle growth, **your body will just convert the excess protein into stored fat** anyway, which is contrary to your goals.

Comment: @Alec - The body will do the same for carbs too, in fact ANY extra calories (Protein, Fata, Carbs) that are consumed will result in an increased body mass. Your daily activities will determine where the weight is added though, similar to what you said.

Comment: @JustSnilloc - Yes, but she has already established that she's on a low-carb diet, so I didn't delve deeper into it.

Comment: I would also advise you to start a lifting/exercise program as soon as you can. That will greatly facilitate weight loss, especially as any fat converted to muscle will automatically increase your caloric burn at rest.

Answer (score 1):

Whey protein powder isn’t anything magical, it’s just protein that has been skimmed out of milk. It is one of the many available sources of protein that you might find when you go to the store. BCAAs likewise are found in every source of protein you can find, the exact amount of each will differ, but it’s nothing to be concerned about.

There is of course a recommended minimum amount of protein that a person should consume daily, but there is also an expected “maximum” that a person can actually utilize. The maximum tends to be about 1.5 grams per kilogram of body weight, but it might be as high as 2 grams. You can eat more than that without concern as the studies that have been done have yet to find an upper limit as to how much protein you can eat without consequences, but don’t go crazy with it. One final note on protein consumption is that it should be spread out through the day, personally I do five meals a day, but there are multiple strategies.

As for your goals, your nutrition will determine your size while your training will determine your shape. I would suggest starting exercise now, if for no other reason than to build the habit. The more lean muscle mass you have, the faster your metabolism will be as well.

Bottom line? Yes, you can have protein shakes for breakfast. However, try to keep your daily nutrition balanced.